# OpenCV/C++ - SIFT keypoint detection and corresponding descriptors

Tags: opencv, detection, sift, keypoint

I have an image. I used Canny edge detector,and then I apply Sift on it.

Here the result :

[image]

I don't understand the result. Why have i some interest points on some black areas and not a lot where I expect the more ?
Besides, what does the circle size refer to ?

I took a look on the internet but it's not totally clear and I don't find any information about it.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Okey i'm going to do this !

Comment: How can one cannot find any information about SIFT....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIFT stands for "Scale-invariant feature transform". It detects keypoints on multiple scales. The circles on your image probably refer to the scale on which the keypoint was detected.

the keypoint positions in black areas don't seem completely unlikely to me: if you suppose that the area they look at is about 2 or 3 times the size of the circle, than the keypoints in the black zone make a lot more sense: it does not just detect a black zone but a zone like this for example; which is distinctive: [image]

**important remark** a keypoint does not mean that only that exact point is different from the rest; it means that that point, together with its surroundings is particular. In the case of SIFT it means that SIFT will be able to detect the same point (or zone if you will) even if you scale the image. The keypoint location returned is then the "centre" of that zone if you will.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer but i don't got it well "if you suppose that the area they look at is about 2 or 3 times the size of the circle, than the keypoints in the black zone make a lot more sense." Could you please try to explain in another way ? Because, On a black area, they are nothing to detect no ?

For your remark, yeah i got it. I know that Sift Detect only particular point which can be compared in others images.

Comment: I better understood. So this black zone is a sort of keypoint because it could be a keypoint in another picture that looks like this picture ?
But when i learned Sift, i saw that Sift used Harris Detector but in a black area,there don't have any corners... That's why i'm a bit confused..

Comment: yes indeed, that is how keypoints work: they are just points that can be found again easily in another image, using their surroundings to find them and mostly using the surroundings as well to describe them

Comment: @lilouch the circle size most probably represents the scale in which the keypoint was found. the bigger the circle the higher in the pyramid. Try to rescale the image (maybe reduced to 1/8 width&height), then you might see why that location isnt just black area but some kind of feature.

Comment: @Micka Okey i got it !
I normalized my picture and i applied Sift again and here the result
[Here](http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_373986Test1Pointinteret.png)
Indeed i don't have any big circle... It's a bit confuse for me but thank you !

Comment: @lilouch Micka didn't say you need to normalize your picture... what SIFT does is RESIZE the picture and detect keypoints at each resized image in the scale-space. Normalizing your picture isn't in any way guaranteeing to remove the big circles...

Comment: @lilouch sorry I didnt want to confuse you. What I wanted to say is, that the big circle shown by Chris Maes in the subimage can be interpreted as the corner of two big black edges. So these keypoints still make sense and can help finding image correspondences.

Comment: Yeah i normalized my image about the size not about colour information. That was you want to say ?

Comment: @lilouch I think you should read a little about SIFT and scale space if you really want to understand.

Comment: some kind of size "normalization" is already done by SIFT internally, thats why it is scale invariant. Thats one good thing about SIFT but the reason why those big points (which make sense) are detected.

Comment: @lilouch but Micka was talking about RESIZING... not normalizing: just look at wikipedia - scale space and that might help you understand.